# Change Image opacity in a CollectionView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In my CollectionView I would like when I select an element, the opacity of an image within the Grid (CheckImage) changes and goes from 0 to 1. and set the background color of the selection to transparent. When I try to select the element even though the background color is set to transparent, it appears orange

```
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                        Value="Transparent"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

<CollectionView               
                x:Name="CategoryView" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding list}"              
                Margin="15,0,15,0"
                SelectionMode="Multiple"
                SelectionChanged="CategoryView_SelectionChanged">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" VerticalItemSpacing="7" HorizontalItemSpacing="7"/>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Source="{Binding Button}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  Text="{Binding Titolo}" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Start"  TextColor="Black" Margin="20,3,0,0"/>
                            <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="0,0,20,10" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                            <Image x:Name="CheckImage" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Check}" Margin="20,0,0,0" Opacity="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

Comment: bind the Opacity value to a property in your model and modify it when the item is selected

Comment: I can't do it. do you have a practical tip with some code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not completed and i guess you use the wrong way for the VisualStateManager. I provided the code sample i made before for your reference.

**Xaml:**

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
     
    <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Accent" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="UnSelected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout
        Padding="10"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="MenuCollection"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Infos}"
            SelectionChanged="MenuCollection_OnSelectionChanged"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout
                    HorizontalItemSpacing="15"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="2"
                    VerticalItemSpacing="15" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Blue">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    </StackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Code:**

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
  {
    public ObservableCollection<Info> Infos { get; set; }
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Infos = new ObservableCollection<Info>
        {
            new Info(){ Title="A"},
            new Info(){ Title="B"},
            new Info(){ Title="B"},
            new Info(){ Title="C"},
            new Info(){ Title="D"}
        };

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void MenuCollection_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    StackLayout lastElementSelected;
    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var s = (StackLayout)sender;
        //s.Style = (Style)Resources["MenuLabelSelectedStyle"];
        if (lastElementSelected != null)
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(lastElementSelected, "UnSelected");

        VisualStateManager.GoToState((StackLayout)sender, "Selected");

        lastElementSelected = (StackLayout)sender;
    }

}
public class Info
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]